# Facebook FQL result set mismatch

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

When I run the following FQL query in two Graph API explorer windows at the same time, I get two different result sets:

```
SELECT 
    post_id, 
    actor_id, 
    target_id, 
    created_time, 
    type, 
    permalink, 
    message, 
    description, 
    attachment 
FROM stream    
WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key 
                    FROM stream_filter 
                    WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') 
ORDER BY created_time ASC 
LIMIT 50
```

Here are the differences:

1. The 1st result set has a few extra posts in the start, whereas the 2nd has a few extra posts in the end (I use ORDER BY created_time ASC in the FQL.)
2. One of the posts in between has an empty permalink in the 1st result set, whereas its present in the 2nd result set.
3. There are few posts not present in the 1st result set which are present in 2nd, and vice versa.

Is this because of load balancing within the Facebook server farm?
How can one make sure they are getting all posts which can be seen on the user's newsfeed via the API?

Comment: I don't see this issue when I paste that query into two different browser windows.  The results are the same.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it all the time when I posted it (I tried about 3-4 times.)